# Setting TTLs when inserting into Cassandra with the Datastax CQL driver

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

Can anyone give me a hint as to why this doesn't work? It doesn't seem to set the TTL; the columns are never deleted. Messing around with INSERT INTO in cqlsh does, though, so there's nothing wrong with Cassandra itself.

```
    StringBuffer cql = new StringBuffer("INSERT INTO ");
    cql.append(getKeyspace());
    cql.append(".taskitems ");
    cql.append(/* long field list */);
    cql.append(" VALUES ");
    cql.append("(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) USING TTL 30");
    //cql.append(getTimeToLive()); // commented out, trying hardcoded value above

    PreparedStatement statement = session.prepare(cql.toString());

    session.execute( statement.bind(
        /* lots o' fields */    
    ));
```

(Cassandra v2.0.0, driver v1.0.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is due to a driver mis-match between datastax-java-driver and Cassandra (either both should be v1 or both should be v2) - try upgrading datastax-java-driver to v2.

It would also be worth using the datastax-java-driver [QueryBuilder](http://www.datastax.com/drivers/java/2.0/apidocs/com/datastax/driver/core/querybuilder/QueryBuilder.html), which is less bug-prone than building String queries manually. (The datastax-java-driver v1 QueryBuilder javadocs is [here](http://www.datastax.com/drivers/java/1.0/apidocs/com/datastax/driver/core/querybuilder/QueryBuilder.html).)

Comment: Hah! You nailed it; changing the library to the latest (2.0.0-rc1) seems to have fixed it. Good call mate.

Comment: Cool, updating my answer to remove the "could" ;-)